# How to get the command short form for custom commands?

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

The built-in Vim command have a nice property. You have only to type as much such that Vim can guess the command.

For `:cclose` you can type:

- `:ccl`
- `:cclo`
- `:cclos`
- `:cclose`

Is there a way to get the same behavior for custom commands without defining 4 times the command?

Comment: They have this by default AFAIK. It’s up to shortest unique prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: The following answer is in the context of neovim. Its codebase has diverged somewhat from that of vim, but the theory should also be applicable to the latter. If there is any discrepancy, feel free to edit my answer with relevant information.

---

As [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) commented, vim does support shortening both system- and user-commands. BUT. There is a difference. System commands look past ambiguous commands, i.e., when there are multiple matches (e.g., `:cc` matches both `:cc` and `:cclose`), system commands won't raise any error; whereas an user-defined command will. The reasons behind it is explained below.

---

Ex commands and user commands are handled differently. The `do_one_cmd` function, which executes the ex command, utilizes `find_ex_command` to expand the ex command. `find_ex_command` only searches in an array of struct `cmdnames`, which is [generated by lua](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/9353e2f7ef6d0919257548e1a43988404900bf03/src/nvim/generators/gen_ex_cmds.lua). [It searches by `strncmp`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/9353e2f7ef6d0919257548e1a43988404900bf03/src/nvim/ex_docmd.c#L2977-L2987), so it can search in the array `cmdnames` for the struct field [`cmd_name`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/9353e2f7ef6d0919257548e1a43988404900bf03/src/nvim/ex_cmds_defs.h#L131) that matches only that many characters. The array is sorted in an arbitrary order (see ref 1 below) of `cmd_name`, which is why `:c`, for example, calls `:change` and not `:cabbrev` (because `:change` appears before `:cabbrev`).

For user-defined commands, there is no such array as `cmdnames`. [`find_ex_command`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/9353e2f7ef6d0919257548e1a43988404900bf03/src/nvim/ex_docmd.c#L2996) calls [`find_ucmd`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/9353e2f7ef6d0919257548e1a43988404900bf03/src/nvim/usercmd.c#L112) function that searches for a user-defined command: first the buffer-local commands and then global commands.

The difference between how vim searches for system commands and user commands is that system commands do not have ambiguity: `:cc` wouldn't raise error and stop because there is another command with one letter more `:ccl`; whereas user-defined commands will not support ambiguous commands. If there are multiple matches, it will raise the following error.

```
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command
```

---

**References**:

1. D. Ben Knoble says, "It’s not entirely arbitrary. Some of this is in fact necessary to support backwards-compatible Vi behavior, where `:c` was always and must be equivalent to `:change`."

---

Comment: Thanks for this very precise answer :-)

Comment: It’s not entirely arbitrary. Some of this is in fact necessary to support backwards-compatible Vi behavior, where `:c' was always and must be equivalent to `:change`. For User commands, as I said, I believe the shortest form is shortest unique prefix.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'll update the "arbitrary" part. The "shortest unique prefix" part is technically wrong, no? If two u-cmds exist: 1) `Ech` and 2)`Echopy`, then `:Ech` is not the shortest "unique" prefix. But it'll be accepted as `:Ech` (bc vim checks if it's a full match).

Comment: Sure, yea, exact matches have to take priority I guess.